# The orthogonal of a set in the Hilbert space $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Consider the sequences Hilbert space of complex numbers $\quad \ell_2=\{x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}^*} \quad|\quad  \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} |x_k|^2<\infty \}$ with the inner product $<x,y>=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} x_k\overline{y_k}$

Let $F$ be the set $F=\{x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}^*} \in \ell_2  \quad|\quad  \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} x_k=0 \}$

What is  $F^\perp$ ?

I tried to pose $f:\ell_2 \to \mathbb{C}$ st $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} x_k$
but the problem is that $f$ is not well definied for instance for the harmonic sequence $(1/k)_k$

Second attempt is write $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} x_k=<x,y>$ st $y=(1,1,...)$ but again $y$ is not in $\ell_2$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit in your attempts.

Comment: @supinf i edited my question.

Comment: @TaylorRendon done

Comment: @Theorem no, the harmonic  sequance is in $\ell_2$ because $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ is a convergence serie =$\pi^2/6$ (Basel problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

Let $y\in F^\perp$ be given.
Since $(1,-1,0,0,\ldots)\in F$, we can make a statement about the relationship
between $y_1$ and $y_2$ that needs to hold.
Similarly, we can make statements about other pairs of components of $y$.

Using these restrictions, you can find an upper bound of the set $F^\perp$.
It remains to show that this upper bound is also a lower bound, which should be the easy part.

Comment: i used your hint and that what i found. Let $y=(y_1,y_2,...) \in F^\perp$ since $(1,-1,...) \in F$ that means that $<y,(1,-1,...)>=0$ so $y_1=y_2$ but again $(0,1,-1,...) \in F$ so $y_2=y_3$ ... so $y_1=y_k$ for all $k \geq 1$ and so the sequence $y$ is a constant but that means that $y=(0,0,...)$ because if not $y$ will be no longer in $\ell_2$ and so $F^\perp=\{0\}$ , is that true?

Comment: @HiddaWalid Yes, correct.